# Is there a loop in R to analyse between columns?

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I have the following data:

```r
df<-read.table(text=" A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5
F   M   F   M   F   17  15  14  17  18
M   M   F   M   F   17  15  12  18  14
F   M   F   M   F   16  12  17  18  16
F   M   F   M   F   13  13  15  17  18
F   M   F   M   F   14  15  17  14  14
M   M   F   F   F   18  14  15  17  18
F   M   F   F   F   16  12  15  17  20
M   F   F   F   F   12  12  18  13  17
F   F   F   F   F   14  12  12  19  16
M   F   F   F   F   18  14  13  12  14
F   F   F   F   F   19  15  14  15  18
F   F   F   M   F   14  20  13  15  19
F   F   F   M   M   18  20  19  13  19
M   F   F   M   M   15  15  12  16  19
F   M   M   M   M   18  14  13  18  18
F   M   M   M   M   17  12  12  13  19
F   M   M   F   M   12  12  13  13  16
M   M   M   F   M   14  19  15  20  14
F   M   M   F   M   18  12  12  12  14", h=T)
```

I want to run a t-test using the following function for groups. For example A1 with B1:

```r
t.test(B1~A1, data=df)
```

```html
ggplot(df, aes(x=B1, y=A1)) + 
geom_boxplot()
```

Now, I want to use a loop to get the output for all data using the t test functin above i.e., A1 with B1, A2 with B2, A3 with B3, A4 with B4 and A5 with B5 and ... So I would get 5 outputs from the t-tests.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Map` to create the formula between corresponding 'A', 'B' columns in a `list` and apply the `t.test`

```
Map(function(x, y) t.test(reformulate(x, y), data = df),
           names(df)[1:5], names(df)[6:10])
```

---

The formula can also be created with `paste`, and wrap with `formula`

```
Map(function(x,y) t.test(as.formula(paste0(y, "~", x)), 
     data = df), names(df)[1:5], names(df)[6:10])
```

---

If we need boxplots

```
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)
map2(names(df)[6:10], names(df)[1:5], ~
   ggplot(df, aes(x = !!rlang::sym(.x), y = !!rlang::sym(.y))) + 
               geom_boxplot())
```

Comment: @User20100  The output is a `list`.  So, it needs to be looped with `lapply` in `base R` or in tidyverse, using `map`.  Also, the example you showed is plotting directly on the data.frame columns and not on the output of ttest

Comment: @User20100  Not sure about your new requirement as the questiion you posted was specifically about t.test

Comment: I am sorry, but I want to make boxplots, too. would you be able to help?

Comment: @User20100  Please post as a new question